# AngularJS and twitter bootstrap number validation in Chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm having an issue with angularjs validation, see http://jsfiddle.net/NR55T/1/. Basically there is a red glow around valid numerical input if the number has digits after the decimal point.

This only seems to happen with Google Chrome (works fine in Firefox) and only when used in conjunction with bootstrap. It will also work fine in Chrome if I leave out the required attribute.

Is my markup invalid or is this an issue with the interaction of the two? If this is an issue is there an easy work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Chrome wants you to specify a [step](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_step.asp) like this to indicate that any increment is valid:

```
<input type="number" step="any" ng-model="Number" required />
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NR55T/2/) is the updated fiddle and see [this](http://blog.isotoma.com/2012/03/html5-input-typenumber-and-decimalsfloats-in-chrome/) for more information on the issue.

Comment: Thanks, interesting to note that you can specify how many decimal places are valid